# Question mark and Colon mark separate statement , anyone explain what's mean of these two operator and portion of statment?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

```
   public static string first_last(string ustr)
    {
        return ustr.Length > 1 ? ustr.Substring(ustr.Length - 1) + ustr.Substring(1, ustr.Length - 2) + ustr.Substring(0, 1) : ustr;
    }
```

I am trying to learn C# syntax.

Comment: That's the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

Comment: It's one operator, the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: The comma's separate parameters being passed to those methods